# How to hide one collapse and open another collapse at same time using sigle button?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add collapse. Below is my code for the purpose.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
       
            <ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-pills" orientation="vertical">
              <li ngbNavItem="a">
                <a ngbNavLink (click)="collapsea.toggle()" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isaCollapsed">A</a>
              </li>
              <li ngbNavItem="b">
                <a ngbNavLink (click)="collapseb.toggle()" [attr.aria-expanded]="isbCollapsed">B</a>
              </li>
              <li ngbNavItem="c">
                <a ngbNavLink (click)="collapsec.toggle()" [attr.aria-expanded]="iscCollapsed">C</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 bg-success">
    
      <div #collapsea="ngbCollapse" [(ngbCollapse)]="isaCollapsed">
       <!-- Content -->
      </div>

      <div #collapseb="ngbCollapse" [(ngbCollapse)]="isbCollapsed">
            <!-- Content -->
      </div>
    
    <div #collapsec="ngbCollapse" [(ngbCollapse)]="iscCollapsed">
      
            <!-- Content -->
    </div>

    
    </div>
```

This is my ts file.

```
export class collapseeComponent implements OnInit {
  public isaCollapsed = false;
  public isbCollapsed = true;
  public iscCollapsed = true;
  
  active = 'A';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

When I run the code, the collapse are appearing. But when I click on second button B, the collapse associated with it gets appended to the first collapse. I want the first collapse A to disappear when I click on B, Similarly, B should disappear when I click on C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call you typescript functions using the (click) event. In these functions you can execute more than one command (strictly speaking, you can also separate multiple calls in your html using semicolon, although it gets messy pretty quickly.

so you could do:

```
<a ngbNavLink (click)="collapsea.toggle(); collapseb.toggle()"...>
```

Personally i prefer function calls

```
<a ngbNavLink (click)="toggle()">

public toggle(): void {
    this.collapsea != this.collapsea;
    this.collapseb != this.collapseb;
}
```

this ngbCollapse is bound to the isaCollapsed boolean, so you can also directly influence these by just setting:

```
this.isaCollapsed != this.isaCollapsed
```

might need to run a changeDetection via injected ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() then, but i doubt it.